# Why is the size of fitted truncated svd model is so big?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, large-data, svd, tf-idf

I have a dataset with tfidf matrix of shape (200000, 565000). I am fitting truncated svd of 500 dimensions from sklearn onto it and pickling the resulting svd object for later use. The pickle file is of size 3 GB. Is it expected size of svd object or am I doing it wrong?

```
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=500, random_state=5)
X_train = svd.fit_transform(tfidf)

svd_path = 'some_path'
with open(svd_path, 'wb') as s:
    pickle.dump(svd, s)
```

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: you are reducing your data to a $500\times 565000$ matrix (plus some other stuff), which has $282.5$ million (presumably double precision) entries thereby occupying $2.26$ billion bytes?

Comment: @whuber, No.  The shape after reduction will be (200000 x 500)